# Receiving Message Multiple times for a client and Message Deletes after one client received

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-service-fabric, servicebus

I have two clients listening to a subscription of topic .  I am seeing following issues.

Issue 1:

If one client receives a message and marks them completes other client won't receive that messages.

But i want all my clients to receive that message and acknowledge it so that once a client receives the message it shouldn't receive again

Issue 2:

If i don't acknowledge the message as complete . Some times i am receiving the message multiple times.

Issue 3:

During the Message Receive if see the Network disconnect. After some time it reconnects  I am receiving the messages from starting again.

For Sending the Message Code

============

```
if (!namespaceManager.TopicExists("DataCollectionTopic"))
                    namespaceManager.CreateTopic("DataCollectionTopic");
            if (!namespaceManager.SubscriptionExists("DataCollectionTopic", "one"))
                namespaceManager.CreateSubscription("DataCollectionTopic", "one");
            for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
            {
            BrokeredMessage bm = new BrokeredMessage("new Topic one");
            bm.Label = "hELLLOOOO xcvxvxcvxvxvxc DummyMEssage"+i;
            bm.Properties["StoreName"] = "asdasdasqwedas";
            bm.Properties["MachineID"] = "Bajjiiiqweq567567wii";

            if (namespaceManager == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nUnexpected Error");
                return;
            }
            MessageSender sender = messageFactory.CreateMessageSender("DataCollectionTopic");
            sender.Send(bm);

for receiving the message

===================


MessageReceiver receiver = await messageFactory.CreateMessageReceiverAsync("DataCollectionTopic/subscriptions/Vijay");

                while (true) { 

                 BrokeredMessage receivedMessage = receiver.Receive();

                try
                {
                  ProcessMessage(receivedMessage);
                 //  receivedMessage.Complete();
                }

                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //  receivedMessage.Abandon();
                }
                }
            }

===============
```

TIA

Comment: Issue 2.  If you don't mark as Complete...eventually, there will be a timeout, that will allow it to be picked up again.

Comment: I ddin't mentioned any time out. As i have n number of clients which may up at any time as soon as they are up they need to receive those messages. but issue is if i restart my client i am receiving already received messages again. Some times i am receiving the messages multiple times

Comment: "Time out" is built in functionality.  I think the default is 30 seconds.  well, it depends.  See "lock duration" here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted/

Comment: You just need to create one subscription per receiver,

Answer (score 1):

**Issue 1**

If both clients receive using the same subscription name, they act as competing consumers. The first consumer to get the message and mark it as completed (processed) will be the winner. The rest of the clients won't process the same message. If intention is to receive a message (event) by **all** clients, then each client should have its own subscription and a copy of the message will be delivered to each subscription.

**Issue 2**

That is an expected behaviour. You receive the message up to [`MaxDeliverCount`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.subscriptiondescription.maxdeliverycount.aspx) and after that message will be DLQ-ed. This is a default behaviour for `PeekLock` mode. With `ReceiveAndDelete` this doesn't happen, but it's a dangerous mode as you will lose the message if not processed successfully.

**Issue 3**

That is an expected behaviour. Each received message in a `PeekLock` mode has a [`LockDuration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription.lockduration.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), time given to a processing code to complete the message or abandon it. If not completed, message becomes visible to other competing consumers and will be reprocessed up to `DeliveryCount` times.

**To sum it up**

1. Have multiple subscriptions per client for all of the clients to receive the same message (event)
2. Complete messages if done processing successfully. If you need time extension, [renew the lock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.renewlock.aspx).